# how to create span exactly like an input textbox

Tags: html, css

I want to create span exactly like an input textbox , but inside the span, it is a href link .

Please advise.

Comment: You should elaborate on what "exactly like an input textbox" means to you. There's a difference between "looks like" and "functions like".

Comment: Yes, and if you mean "looks like", you're out of luck, because all the browssrs display input text boxes differently. In the future, there will be a CSS keyword `appearance`, but that's not here yet.

Comment: the outlook should be same as the input. don't need input textbox functions

Comment: still ambiguity in your question, don't exactly know what you want; may be some thing like this;
http://jsfiddle.net/4mgXc/

Comment: what the hell are people down voting this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to "deceive" a user by making an `a` tag look like an `input`, but I will trust your reasoning is honorable. Mr Lister had a good comment that different browsers render `input` differently. That being so, I think your best bet at getting something that works fairly well cross-browser is [something like this (the first in the example is a link, the second a real input to compare)](http://jsfiddle.net/vzRqY/17/).

I only tested this in FF. I set the opacity of the text in the `a` through the `rgba` to hide it but keep it for search engine purposes (so you don't just have an empty `a` tag as far as the search engines are concerned). In using a "real" `input` to achieve the look, it adds non-semantic html, but it does allow for better cross-browser rendering of the box.

**HTML**

```
<span class="fakeInput">
   <input type="text" value="Your link"/>
   <a href="#">Your link</a>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.fakeInput {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px;
}

.fakeInput input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

.fakeInput a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0); /*hide anchor text, let input show */
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```